# laravel uploading pic path showing zero

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

WHen uploading, all data is inserted in table except pic_path column contains 0. Am i doing wrong when processing file uploaded:

This is the controller:

```
if(Session::has('userLogged'))
        {
            if($_POST)
            {
                $file;
                if (Input::hasFile('pic'))
                {

                    $file = Input::file('pic');
                    print_r($file);
                }

                $validator = $this->validate(Input::all(), $rules);

                if ($validator != null)
                {

                    return Redirect::to('basicDetails')->withErrors($validator);

                }else{

                    $title = Input::get('title');
                    $summary = Input::get('summary');
                    $description = Input::get('description');
                    $destinationPath = base_path() . '/public/img';
                    $file->move($destinationPath);
                    $path = $file->getRealPath();
                    $personModel = new Course;
                    $personeModel->basicDetails($title, $summary, $description, $path);
                }
```

and this is form url:

```
{{ Form::open(array('action' => 'PersonController@basic','files' => true)) }}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before move the file get the path:

```
$title = Input::get('title');
$summary = Input::get('summary');
$description = Input::get('description');
$destinationPath = base_path() . '/public/img';


$path = $file->getRealPath();

$file->move($destinationPath);


$personModel = new Course;
$personeModel->basicDetails($title, $summary, $description, $path);
```

I am not sure why you need uploaded path? Usually this is the temp path where Laravel uploaded the file.

http://laravel.com/docs/requests#files

Comment: Aha didn't know it was only temp path. What path should I store to load the picture from later in <img>? is it destinationPath above?

Comment: Yes, its destination path. However, You need image file name as well. So, destinationPath + filename.jpg.